# How and where I can log the fail payment error for all Payment method in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, error-log

I want to log **error** on payment fails on checkout page but I can not find the way to where I can log the error message for all the payment method?

**For example:**

1) I selected the PayPal payment method and press continue button at that time it returns a message like that.

[image]

I want to log this type of error message on save payment.

I have tried `savePaymentAction` but I can not find it there.

Is there any event or method where can I log it?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `failure.phtml` or failure event  or dispatch  event for failure.